# Workspace / sub project / cocoa pods - lexical preprocessor issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm trying to add cocoa pods to project, I've had a few attempts but I also end up with a lexical / preprocessor issue error. For a h file in my sub project.

I've managed to pinpoint exactly when the error occurs, which surprises me.

I have a sub project added to my project, a modified calendar library from github.

First, I add a workspace file and re-open my workspace file and build, everything works fine, which is when I expected the lexical / preprocessor error would occur.

I've already setup my pod file.

I then run pod setup, then pod install.

I get a warning saying I need to add $(inherited) to link flags.
I've tried building before and after adding this.
This warning goes away.

However I always get the lexical / preprocessor error.

I've tried adding the sub project my target schemes too.

I've also got the a file in the target dependencies.

I would expect my h file to autocomplete when I type an import but it doesn't, not even the sub project itself. e.g.

Hash import < whatever\whatever.h >

So it looks like I'm missing a path in a setting maybe ?

Thanks in advance, not sure what else to do, been googling extensively :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for a bit longer I found I needed to set the search header value for my project to the two cocoapods had put in my target.

Then for each of my targets add $(inherited) then the link to my sub project $(srcroot)/subproject.

:)